# Array: Merge keys and values, to call as an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

How to code a pure JS.

To call this content:

```
var keys = ["height", "width"];
var values = [["12px", "24px"],["127px", "284px"]...];
```

Into readable referral object:

Simple `values_line[1].height`
may return
`127px`

Try this code:
`var array = keys.map((el, i) => { return [keys[i], values[i]]; });`

But it work only to match key to value One time only.

```
console.log(array);
// → [["height", "12px"], ["width", "24px"]]
var output = Object.fromEntries(array);
// → {height: "12px", width: "24px"}
console.log(output);
```

or even

```
 var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
         result[keys[i]] = values[i];
```

Any idea to create object of full "table" with title/head names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each value, map over the `keys` array to create a tuple of `[key, value]`, then use `Object.fromEntries` to construct your object.

```js
var keys = ["height", "width"];
var values = [["12px", "24px"],["127px", "284px"]];

var dimensions = values.map(value => (
  Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, index) => ([key, value[index]])))
));

console.log(dimensions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `values` using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

At each iteration, create an object from `keys` using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) representing key-value pairs, where its values are from the current list according to the `index`:

```js
const 
  keys = ["height", "width"],
  values = [["12px", "24px"],["127px", "284px"]];

const values_line = values.map(currentValues => 
  keys.reduce((acc, key, index) => ({ ...acc, [key]: currentValues[index]}), {})
);

console.log(values_line);
```

Using `for-loops`:

```js
const 
  keys = ["height", "width"],
  values = [["12px", "24px"],["127px", "284px"]];

const values_line = [];

for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  const currentValues = values[i];
  const currentObj = {};
  for(let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    const key = keys[j];
    currentObj[key] = currentValues[j];
  }
  values_line[i] = currentObj;
}

console.log(values_line);
```